# Should I create a stored procedure on the database being read from or the database being written to?

Tags: t-sql, ssms

I'm creating a stored procedure (and a schedule/job to execute the procedure every 5 minutes) which will read data from a table in one database, and write data to another table in a different database.

Does it matter whether I create the stored procedure on the database being read from, or the database being written to?

EDIT: It's a small procedure which showed to have taken 0 seconds to perform.

Answer (score 1):

Without any special information, you could do any of the two. It would be called either "push" or "pull". One idea would be to put the burden of the proc on the database with least traffic.

Moving data between systems is usually done in ETL steps - Extract, Transform, Load. What makes it easier for my thinking usually is to export original data from source db to destination db, and then do both the processing and the final insertions on the target one. In this case, I'll put the spc on the destination db, since most things (except the first data transfer) happen there.

This is just a rule of thumb that has proved convenient over a few years. I am interested myself in other answers.

Last but not least, if there are no transformations needed, consider replication.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best practice is to create procedure in database where you are insert/update your data. Like so you can manage all your stored procedures easy. Like a source and target, better to store your code in target, so target will be independent. So I think it is more manageable to store your stored procedures in a target database.

Answer (score 1):

Neither.

An operational concern should be solved using an operational approach.

Neither database should "know" this operation is being performed - having operational code in the database increases testing complexitiy and moves the database closer to being a swiss army knife (which is bad).

Rather, an intermediate agent running separately from either database should control the operation.

Create a script to:

- export the data from the source database to a file using database utilites
- move the file to the target database
- import the data fromt he file using database utilities

Schedule the script to run using crontab or whatever scheduling/workflow tool you choose (*not* using either database in any way to schedule).

Comment: I'm guessing that avoiding the swiss army solution is a double-edged knife in itself. Your solution sounds too complex for me, I'd rather use as few steps as possible. Maybe you are used to larger scale, where things are so big that assigning specific roles to systems is more important that having fewer systems themselves? Your rep sure indicates toward that direction ^^

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis abstracting the implementation away inside a script is desirable, because you shouldn’t have to modify the database (required to change a stored proc) to change how data is moved between databases - the movement has nothing to do with either DB directly, and the motivation to change is *operational*, not in the RDBMS wheelhouse. You could just start with a simple SQL only approach for the script, like `insert into db2.table select * from db1.table where …`

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing anything else? If you have a project that importing data from DB1 to DB2 then you need to create another stored procedure to work with data in DB2, I would create it on DB2.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).